# Does a field of a struct count as a variable? Does an element of an array count as a variable?

Tags: c, arrays, variables, struct

I know both arrays and structs count as variables, but do their fields/elements?

I'm trying to write some documentation about a program that deals with deeply nested structs and arrays, but don't know if I can refer to these fields/elements as variables.

Comment: I could say that neither answer clarifies something. Definition of a struct specifies a type. The term variable refers to an instance of that type (or, in OOP terms, object is an instance of a class). You are mixing these terms, so please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ordinary documentation, words like "variable" take their meaning from context.  Other options would be "value" or "datum"/"data".  As long as your explanation of your interface is clear and consistent, it probably doesn't matter which of those you use.

(Language in Standards, and discussion of Standards, is something else.  In that case, more precision and lots of definitions are required.)

Answer (score 1):

Array elements and structure members are not variables, nor does memory obtained via `malloc` constitute a variable. In C, variables have a name, scope, and storage duration. The word you're looking for is "object".

Comment: Downvoter, care to comment? Go read the C standard and you'll find it agrees with my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you shouldn't refer to them as variables. As R. states correctly, "variable" is a well defined term in C. What you probably mean are objects. Objects may or may not be referenced by variables, you may take their addresses, and it makes complete sense to talk of partial objects, e.g talking of an `int` object that is part of a structure object.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can call them variables, assuming they vary.

Comment: C has variables which cannot vary: `const`-qualified variables. :-)

Comment: @R: Are those really variables?  I always thought of them as constant terms.

Comment: They are variables. Read the standard. C is not C++.

Comment: Nobody cares what an individual language spec says if it blatantly distorts the English language. It's a spec written by programmers, who obviously aren't the most literate people. Variable has a clear definition in any dictionary, and constant variable is an oxymoron.

Comment: @R: The standard (C99 §6.7.3:5) seems to talk about objects defined with const-qualified types, not const-qualified variables.  Despite what @Mark H said, I do care.  Can you point me to mention of const-qualified variables?

Answer (score 0):

The data members of a C struct are called fields.

```
struct Person {
  int age;
  int height;
};
```

age and height are fields of this struct. You can create a new Person and its fields are variable based on your handle on the struct.

```
struct Person a;
a.age = 20;      // age and height are variable. You can change them
a.height = 100;

const struct Person b = {20, 100};
b.age = 10; // compiler error. Person b is a const. age/height are not variable.
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

structures and arrays are data types and not variables.

structures are composite types made of other types.

[This article](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fundamentals_of_C_Programming/Preliminaries#What_is_a_variable.3F) may help explain what a variable is.

Another article is [here](http://begincprogram.blogspot.com/2009/05/session-2-variables-and-data-types.html)